# Approach for web application to act as Restfull application

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

we are trying to develop a web application where controllers(Servlets) should act as restfully services , initially browser will act as client and then in future there could be third party applications which will be consuming services from the same controllers.

All controllers will return JSON data and angular JS will use this and display content in browser for the web application and for the third party application they will directly invoke rest services.

My question are as follows

- If i am developing Restful service then should I not use HTTP-session
  i.e should my controllers be completely stateless
- If my application should be stateless then how will I overcome the
  shortage of    HTTP-session object ( how do i carry the user specific
  data which    could be required in different screen)
- How will the authentication    be handled for the third party
  application , should user provide    credentials in each request ?

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, you need a kind of token based authentication, in other words you have to set header with each request. Angular ngResource is your friend. Example:

```
i.   Login (Basic Authentication)
ii.  Get Token from Server and store it e.g. in Cookies 
iii. Set header with each request (token: whatever)
iv.  If token is valid, server answers with data or enables further interaction
```

2) User specific data will be stored in your $scope (Angular Term) ist is like a data and operation container for your model. You can persist it locally if you want to. Or send it to the server (with a valid token to store it there)

3) Login, get Token, communicate. User rights and Co. has to be set correctly on the server.

Comment: For web application too i have to use basic Auth , I want to use login page .but that should not matter right either login page or basic auth it is all about setting in cookie  or in request headers                                                                                           For Restfull webservice how do i do basic auth should  or they should  set username/password in headers and then send request each time (including first time)

Comment: Step1: Login. If your login is correct, you will get an answer with a token from your REST-Server. You have to store it locally. Then you will send an Header including this token. Server will let you get the ressources, as long as your token is valid and you are not logged out.

Comment: Should i never use a form login page for Restfull webservice even if the client is my own html page i.e a web application rather then any other third party appilcation